# AngularJs ui-router и otherwise

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Вот есть конфигурация маршрутизации

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider', function($locationProvider,$stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
            .state('page', {
                url: "/page:page",
                views: {
                    "viewVideo": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                            return '/lesson/'+stateParams.page+'video.html';
                        }
                    },
                    "viewText": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                             return '/lesson/'+stateParams.page+'text.html';
                        }
                    },
                    "viewQuiz": {
                        templateUrl: function (stateParams){
                             return '/lesson/'+stateParams.page+'quiz.html';
                        }
                    }
                },
            })
    }]);
```

Работает нормально. Хотел добавить метод, если адрес неверный(не соответствует url state) - редиректило на другую страничку или на

```
.state('page', {
                    url: "/page:1",
```

Если прописываю

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($locationProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("page");
```

ничего не происходит

Пример на гите

```
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
```

Припустим я делаю вот так по примеру:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/error");
.state('error', {
                url: "/error",
                views: {
                    "viewVideo": {
                        template: 'Недоступно'
                    },
                    "viewText": {
                        template: 'Недоступно'
                    },
                    "viewQuiz": {
                        template: 'Недоступно'
                    }
                }
            })
```

Что не так?

Comment: параметр это не имя state а урл

Comment: добавил пример без параметра по аналогии с документации гита, что упустил или не понял? запутался с одинаковыми названиями state и url

Comment: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("page");` вот тут должно быть не имя state, а урл для него `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/page");` ну и на всякий случай стоит глянуть консоль, может там ошибки есть

Comment: в консоли ошибок нет, прописал аналогично, никакого результата

Comment: тогда нужен пример на plunkr :-)

Comment: мог бы попробовать загнать на plunkr, но можно ли там протестировать работу с заменой url в адресной строке? это же главное что нужно протестировать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34651/discussion-between-grundy-and--).